# Unable to authenticate when trying to add photos or albums through Google Picasa API

Tags: python, api, authentication, photo, picasa

I am trying to upload a photo to an album through Picasa's API, however I am getting an authentication error.

My credentials are being successfully authenticated right when the program starts, just not when I am trying to upload a photo or add an album

Here is the code I have:

```
import gdata.photos.service
import gdata.media
import gdata.geo

gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()
gd_client.email = 'username@gmail.com'
gd_client.password = 'password'
gd_client.source = 'exampleCo-exampleApp-1'
gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

username = 'username'
albums = gd_client.GetUserFeed(user=username)
album_id = albums.entry[0].gphoto_id.text
album_url = '/data/feed/api/user/%s/albumid/%s' % (username, album_id)
path = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg'

album = gd_client.InsertAlbum(title='New album', summary='This is an album')

photo = gd_client.InsertPhotoSimple(album_url, 'New Photo', 
    'Uploaded using the API', path, content_type='image/jpeg')
```

Here is the error I am receiving when I try to add an album or upload a photo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1020071/Documents/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    album = gd_client.InsertAlbum(title='New album', summary='This is an album')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\photos\service.py", line 358, in InsertAlbum
    raise GooglePhotosException(e.args[0])
GooglePhotosException: (403, 'Forbidden', 'Modification only allowed with api authentication.')
```

This is the guide I have been following: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python#request-a-list-of-albums

Comment: Not the issue but  use raw strings or forward slashes in your paths

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually make the change over OAuth2?  The following code should work:

```
def OAuth2Login(client_secrets, credential_store, email):
scope='https://picasaweb.google.com/data/'
user_agent='testingApp'

storage = Storage(credential_store)
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(client_secrets, scope=scope, redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
    uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    webbrowser.open(uri)
    code = raw_input('Enter the authentication code: ').strip()
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
    storage.put(credentials)

if (credentials.token_expiry - datetime.utcnow()) < timedelta(minutes=5):
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    credentials.refresh(http)

gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService(source=user_agent,
                                           email=email,
                                           additional_headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % credentials.access_token})

return gd_client
album = gd_client.InsertAlbum('test', 'My Test Album', access='protected')
```

You should create an API Key in the Google developer portal and download the json secret.  This repo was very helpful https://github.com/MicOestergaard/picasawebuploader#authentication.