# Unable to create album in Google Photos via python gdata api

Tags: python, api, gdata, google-photos

I am trying to upload photos to Google photos via python gdata api.
This script used to work until last month but is failing now.
The InsertAlbum API fails to upload with error 501 ( Not Implemented)

```
gdata.photos.service.GooglePhotosException: (501, 'Not Implemented', 'Insert is no longer supported')
```

Is there any change in how albums are created?

The script was inspired by [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509364/unable-to-authenticate-when-trying-to-add-photos-or-albums-through-google-picasa).
The full script is [here](https://gist.github.com/prateeksriv/75a628c6e4012df1db2a9f4ae65b35c6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has released V3 api last month and it has deprecated many methods like creating albums, etc. See below url for details

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide

Thanks.